# Dockerising a node app

Tags: node.js, shell, docker

I was trying to dockerise the project [etherpad-lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite) on Github.

The folder structure is in this manner:

```
etherpad-lite
├── bin
│   ├──run.sh
│   └── <some more files and dirs>
├── node_modules
│   └── ep_etherpad-lite -> ../src
├── src
│   ├── node
│   │   ├── <contains server.js>
│   │   ├── some other files
│   ├── <contains Dockerfile and package.json>
├── <some other dirs>
```

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app3
COPY package.json /app3
RUN npm install
COPY . /app3
RUN cd ..
CMD ./bin/run.sh
EXPOSE 9001
```

I ran the following command to build the image:

```
sudo docker build -t docker-etherpad-lite .
```

The output was as follows:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  89.56MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:8
 ---> baf6417c4cac
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a3d6f291156
Step 3/8 : COPY package.json /app3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7670bee8c3a6
Step 4/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9e664f008cf9
Step 5/8 : COPY . /app3
 ---> 81b1633b14a2
Step 6/8 : RUN cd ..
 ---> Running in c3fa14639657
Removing intermediate container c3fa14639657
 ---> c90c071f8c49
Step 7/8 : CMD ./bin/run.sh
 ---> Running in 7964e382cee7
Removing intermediate container 7964e382cee7
 ---> 2a93b0c66d0b
Step 8/8 : EXPOSE 9001
 ---> Running in 2df13cd2bfa3
Removing intermediate container 2df13cd2bfa3
 ---> b75e9fc149ae
Successfully built b75e9fc149ae
Successfully tagged docker-etherpad-lite:latest
```

But while trying to run the same, I faced this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./bin/run.sh: not found
```

Am I doing something wrong? OR is there a problem with the bash? 
Do I have to add command like this FROM debian:ubuntu in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Is `./bin/run.sh` executable? `chmod +x ./bin/run.sh` and rebuild the image, then try again.

Alternatively, you can "enter" the container and troubleshoot directly: `docker run --rm --interactive --tty --entrypoint sh docker-etherpad-lite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got an answer to my question. Actually, I placed my Dockerfile inside the src folder and so the container-image that Docker built did not contain the rest of the folders (including bin). For this reason, it showed the error bin/run.sh not found.
The error was easily resolved by keeping the Dockerfile in the root folder(etherpad-lite) and doing a few modifications in the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app3
COPY . /app3
CMD ./bin/run.sh
EXPOSE 9001
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the `CMD` line in the Dockerfile

CMD /app3/bin/run.sh

Be also sure to have `chmod +x bin/run.sh`